# WIX toolset: Store (configurable) Install directory inside registry

Tags: wix, installation, windows-installer

I am using the feature tree dialog set which allows for a customised install directory, I am then trying to store this install directory inside a registry

As per Wix's documentation I am defaulting the ui variable to the directory I want

```
<Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="VERSION" />
<SetProperty Id="VERSION" Value="[ProgramFilesFolder]Thermo\SampleManager\[PROP_VERSION]" After="CostInitialize" />
```

Then trying to set the registry as follow

```
            <RegistryKey Root="HKCR" Key="x\x\x">
                <RegistryValue Type="string" Value="[VERSION]aaasx\aasx" />
            </RegistryKey>
```

Obviously the [VERSION] does not change with the UI selection, which variable should I be using to change the configured directory? Feel as if I've tried every suggested [INSTALLDIR] etc.

Directory is configured as such

```
<Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder" Name="PFiles">
            <Directory Id="COMPANY" Name="Company">
                <Directory Id="PRODUCT" Name="Product">
                    <Directory Id="VERSION" Name="Version">
```

Further investigation found that using file references ( [#file] ) works, which solves 90% of my problems, however pointing/storing a directory path does not work

Answer (score 1):

You can use only *RegistryValue* like that:

`<RegistryValue Root='HKCR' Key='SOFTWARE\MyProcudt'
                Name='MyPath' Value='[INSTALLDIR]'
                Type='string' />`

It will create registry in HKCR/software/myproduct name "mypath" with value [installdir] (set ealrier).

Comment: So this, rather than nesting inside a <RegistryKey Root="HKCR" Key="x\x\x">?

Comment: Yes, exactly :) i create it in _Component_ element.

Comment: No change with <RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key="yada/yada" Type="string" Value="[INSTALLDIR]x\x" />         the install just puts x/x inside the registry as though the [INSTALLDIR] is null/blank

Comment: What directory you want to put there? can you show Directory structure? Or even you can use your property _Version_ (as you showed us in question) like that: `Value="[VERSION]"`. Also, _key_ is path from root, its like HKCR\yada\yada. Remember to use backslaches! _Value_ **name** of registry key.

Comment: VERSION appears to have worked (it was my original solution) however modifying the install directory at install time, it remains the same as default

Comment: Are you using _InstallDirDlg.wxs_? Then you should use WIXUI_INSTALLDIR property to get folder.

Comment: FeatureTree, but I believe it uses the same variable. When using that variable however the registry just stores 'VERSION' maybe I am doing something wrong setting the default?